# Function annotations in python2

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Is it possible to use function annotations in python2.7?

i.e. code like this produce invalid syntax in python2.7, but works in python3.5

```
def apply(self, img_bgr) -> np.array:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Python type hints were introduced in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), implemented in Python 3.5. Therefore, they are not available on Python 2.x (or even Python 3.4).

Also, beware [Python 2 EOL](https://pythonclock.org/) - I suggest transitioning from Python 2 as soon as possible.